# Userscript to hide elements containing certain words

Tags: javascript, java, html, userscripts

I want to make an userscript that can hide specific elements on a website.
- I only want it to hide elements that contain for example M23 M53
- BUT i want to keep all elements with for example K42 K22
How would i code something like this?
All the elements are built in the same class.
" M27"
Code example:

```
<div class="l1 picshadow" style="display:inline-block;width:240px;padding:10px;height:110px;margin:5px;border-radius:2px;text-align:left;position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;"><div class="ssmall" style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:10px;"><p style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:0px;" class="ssmall"> Göteborg, Västra Götalands län</p><p style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:0px;" class="ssmall">Inloggad i 14 dygn 6 tim 34 min</p></div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" width="48" align="left"><a href="profil.php?id=68006&amp;src=inloggade"><img src= class="picshadow" width="40" height="52" border="0"></a></td><td valign="top"><a href="profil.php?id=68006&amp;src=inloggade"><b>Koneko</b></a> M27</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Would this be very hard to code or ?

Comment: Cna you un-minify your code so it is esier to read it?